# Google Analytics on Intranet without public visibility

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, intranet

I need to track an intranet site's traffic and would prefer to use Google Analytics because we have several other properties already being tracked there.

Google Analytics requires a public address to set up a new property for tracking. If I create a subdomain (intranet.domain.com) to satisfy that requirement, I believe the rest should work fine. (External .js file for Google is outbound-reachable from within our network, inbound-external access is blocked to protect confidential information.)

1. Does anyone have experience with this situation? Can you confirm the
   proposed method will work?
2. Will the new tracking code work from any URL, regardless of the registered property address?

Thanks!

Comment: Solution has been implemented - Google Analytics is up & running!

Comment: A public address / FQDN makes GA setup easier but there are workarounds if this isn't possible. But GA is an advertising reporting platform, not an Intranet reporting platform:  http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/google-analytics-for-intranet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics records data via parameters on tracking pixel requests. You need to make sure that requests for google-analytics.com/__utm.gif will go through from your intranet. (I'm guessing it shouldn't be an issue since you said google-analytics.com/ga.js is not blocked.)

It's also not a problem using the web property ID ('UA-xxxxx-x') on different domains than it was originally created for.